# firebase init won't run after running npm install -g firebase-tools -f

Tags: windows, firebase, firebase-tools

I am following the steps in Firebase to setup functions. I ran npm install -g firebase-tools -f and didn't get any errors but when I try to run firebase init I get this error:
[image]

I am running Windows 10, Flutter version: 3.13.2

I have tried the recommendations I found here but none of them work for me.
I have added the npm folder to my path variable.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.  This is especially importnat for others in the future who want to use the error message in a web search to find this solution (your image text will not be readily searchable).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I will try to do this from now on. In this particular instance, I was not able to copy the message text so I had to use an image.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser